# Is there possibilty in numpy to swap x,y of matrix without changing memory order and iterators?

Tags: image, numpy, matrix, iterator, memory-layout

I'm trying to switch to **numpy** from the world of **fortran** and **c++**.
Mainly I'm working with huge images, where coordinates directions are x: left to right, y: top down, and pixels are stored in rows, common for image format.

Numpy says that also stores matrices by rows. As far as good, it is the same as fortran/c++ saves images. But, see following example, grays from black to white in rows. Lets create image 3x3 where first row is 123 etc

[Black to White image as expected, with matplotlib imshow(mat)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJGtz.png)

```
mat = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'i1').reshape(3,3)
```

next I've used following code to get info about matrix. Routine prints: value at position `x=1, y=0`, position in memory to see if array is copied, strides and iterators.

```
def pr(a):
    x=1; y=0;
    print(a[x,y])
    print(a.ctypes.data, a.strides, a.ravel(order='K'), [x for x in a.flat], a.flatten(order='K'))
    print(a.flags)
```

for matrix `mat` in **C-order** I've got

```
4
94598176807408 (3, 1) [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
```

So it is clear that `x,y` are swapped, because for `x=1` and `y=0` pixel value is 2 and not 4, so I've changed to F order.

```
# mat = mat.ravel(order='K').reshape(3,3, order='F')
mat.strides = (1,3)
# mat = np.swapaxes(mat, 0, 1)
```

Above are three possibilities to get **F order** with same results.

```
2
94598176807408 (1, 3) [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
```

[Now image is swapped when using F order with same memory layout as before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNuv1.png)

As you can see value 2 for `x=1 y=2` is correct, using `mat[x,y]` is correct, memory order is correct, but iterator is wrong `1 4 7 ...`.
Consequences are that saving or showing image are bad, all are swapped. Iterator not in memory order has big performance penalties.

Question is: How to set numpy matrix with swapped x,y without copy of image and all other properties are as in C-order. I've tried to set C_CONTIGUOUS=True, but it is not possible.?

One way is to use C-order but on all such matrices one must use reversed indexes [y,x],  problem is that it is very confusing, all vectors are normal `(x,y,z)` and some objects use swap index order.? Correct naming order of axes helps in further spatial operation of images.

Maybe there is possibility to extend **numpy**, with other index method like `mat.swap2[x,y]` that only returns `mat[y,x]` or eg. `mat[*reversed((x,y))]`. But
is there better solution?

Next are two examples in **fortran** and **c++** with eg. armadillo matrix library (as c/c++ doesn't seem to define own generic matrix object). Both examples uses F order, indexing is correct `mat[x,y]`, memory layout is same as binary layout of input images, row by row, iterator are in memory layout. It seems strange to me that numpy in F order does not support same behavior. Or simply I don't understand the philosophy of numpy.

Example in **fortran**, saving and iterating such matrix is in memory order (not shown here).

```
...
    integer(1) :: mat(0:2,0:2)      ! matrix 3x3 indexing 0,1,2
    data mat /1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/    ! memory order
    print*, mat(1,0)                ! value for x=1 y=0 is 2 ok
...
```

Example in **C++** with armadillo, saving and iterating again is in memory order (not shown here).

```
#define ARMA_U8_TYPE   uint8_t
#define ARMA_S8_TYPE    int8_t        // define support for int8 instead of char
#include <armadillo>
...
    using namespace arma;
    int8_t amem[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};        // memory order
    Mat<int8_t> mat(amem, 3,3,  false,true);    // matrix 3x3
    cout << (int)mat(1,0) << "\n";              // value for x=1 y=0 is 2 ok
...
```

Comment: When working with arrays more than 2d, the `shape` and `strides` tells me more than the `order` or `flags`.  For all arrays, the data is actually stored in a 1d `c` array.  It's the shape/strides that determines the traversal order.

Answer (score 0):

First numpy has confusing terms for column major mode, `F_CONTIGUOUS` is never contiguous in memory for 2D and more. It is just like view by design and memory layout is always `C`.
For performance reasons and axis assignment as you specified it is more natural to use column major order as many do, but not easy in numpy.

Furthermore built-in/extension doesn't allow to use just `setattr()` to extend directly numpy classes, but you can derive own.

To be simple in numpy always use default `C` order (row major order) and swap axes as `mat[z,y,x]`. It seems to me to be the least confusing.